# Does "Running Ragged" hat count on the Stack Overflow leaderboard?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

I see [here](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard) that there is a winter bash leaderboard per site, and when one gets a hat the description says to which site that hat belongs:

[image]

So is the "Running Ragged" hat never going to be awarded to Stack Overflow? Or as it is being awarded to all sites because of being a hat that requires collaboration on multiple Stack Exchange sites?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Running Ragged is one of two hats, the other being Polymath, that you cannot earn on Stack Overflow.  Since neither one can be earned on Stack Overflow, they will not be shown on the leaderboard.

This was done specifically because Stack Overflow has two hats, The NeverEnding Story and What's Up, Doc, that can't be earned on the rest of the network.  We wanted to make the total number of hats earned on both Stack Overflow and the rest of the network the same.

Answer (score 2):

No. Stack Overflow will never get that hat. Those hats were added to balance the What's up, Doc? and The NeverEnding Story hats that can only be awarded on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

The wording is the same as on the Polymath badge

> post at least one well-received answer on three different sites during Winter Bash (not including Stack Overflow)

which you can earn *multiple times* (but not on Stack Overflow). It will *not* count on the Stack Overflow hat leaderboard - hats don't count cross-site.